# Allowing user to browse to a directory

Tags: angularjs, directory, user-input

I'm working on an AngularJS application.  There is a form where the user can input a path into a textbox.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="source_path">Source Path:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="source_path" ng-model="jobs.source_path" required>
</div>
```

At the moment, this requires the user to open a file browser on their local machine, navigate to the directory on the server, and paste that file path into the text box. I would like to make this a bit more user friendly by adding a `Browse` button that allows them to browse to the directory and select it, populating the text box, without having to copy and paste.

---

I cannot seem to find a way to allow the user to select the directory path.  Everything I've been finding is for uploading a specific file. Is this possible? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You have to use file type for input to achieve this. https://jsfiddle.net/oghjx62w/2/

Comment: @Vivz I need the file to not be uploaded though

Comment: Maybe something like this will suffice https://jsfiddle.net/oghjx62w/3/ ?

Comment: @Vivz I think it might actually not be possible.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav  
Looks like browsers prevent it from being possible

Comment: So basically you can only show the file name but not the full path. The above method will only work for filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently **not possible.**  For security reasons, browsers will not allow access to the full path of a file.